# Do you need the axiom of choice if the non-empty sets in question are defined recursively?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, foundations

Suppose I pick (using a single choice) an element $q_1$ from a nonempty set $U$. I then pick $q_2$ from the set $U/\{q_1\}$, $q_3$ from the set $U/\{q_1, q_2\}$ and so on. At each stage, the set in question is guaranteed to be non-empty. Thus, I have constructed a sequence $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ using a single choice each time. Thus, I can safely assume that no (countably infinite) axiom of choice was used in the construction of this sequence, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have in fact used a weak form of the axiom of choice, specifically, the [axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice). Without choice you can make any **finite** number of arbitrary choices, but you cannot in general make an infinite sequence of them.